# OmniSharp server is not running macOS 10.13.6

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-4.0

OmniSharp server is not running on my VS code. I tried with reinstall both VS code and C# extension powered by omniSharp, but it is still not running. I am working in a macOS 10.13.6.
So I do not get any error (red highlighting in case inaccurate code ) or in my code. Any advise how to solve this?

[image: pic from VS code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not familiar with OmniSharp, but this may be of use (unless you've already followed it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp). With regards to debugging, perhaps this may help: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Desktop-.NET-Framework.

>The C# extension supports limited full .NET framework debugging. It can only debug 64-bit applications with portable PDBs.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these [steps](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3990#issuecomment-675227919):

- Go to the VSCode settings (File > Preferences > Settings).
- Search with the keywords omnisharp use global mono to locate the configuration.
- Change the value to never from either auto or always.
- REMEMBER to restart the VSCode to activate the change (I restarted it twice to be sure).

Comment: after following your instruction, Now can start omniSharp server, But still not getting any error highlighting..

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling of **an older version** of **C# extension** solved my problem. Now OmniSharp is functioning fine.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"` to `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never"` in settings.json file and now it's working for me.

You can open the "settings.json" file from ctrl+p and type "settings.json" to opened window.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue with Omnisharp on my MacOs 13.1 and my solution is to specify exact path to the `.net` since I have multiple versions installed.

Go to the VSCode Settings and search for "omnisharp: Sdk Path", there, you can specify exact path to the `.net` sdk and restart VSCode afterwards (see screenshots below).

[image]

And if you're not sure what is the correct path to your `.net` sdk, you'll find it by running `dotnet --info` command in your terminal; you will get something like this:

[image]

I hope it helps, cheers!